# formatting (,) in result MySQL

Tags: mysql

good morning everyone,

i have a table that looks like this, using format() i can put (,) on my begbalance, deposit and withdraw table which are all decimals.

```
| begbalance | deposit | withdraw |

SELECT  format(begbalance,2)begbalance,
    format(deposit,2)deposit,
    format(withdraw,2)withdraw, 
    begbalance+deposit+withdraw AS balance
FROM savingstable;
```

my problem is i cant use format() balance, i want to put comma (,) in balance. any suggestion?  thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
format(begbalance+deposit+withdraw, 2) as balance
```